# Картинки в описании привилегии "Принимать Описания Меток"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Картинки в конце описания привилегии ["Принимать Описания Меток"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), приведенные для образца, содержат английский текст (английские названия знаков).
Должно быть написано "Редактор меток" вместо "Tag Editor", к примеру.
Наверняка, проблема актуальна не только для этой статьи.

[image: редактирование_меток]

Comment: И в привилегии "[Голосовать за](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)".

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть новые картинки и я не побоюсь их использовать!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно только статью открыть на редактирование. :)

Comment: А можно ли добавить знаки не картинками, а хтмл-кодом, как [в списке](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)?